# How to transfer data to UI in winforms from children class?

Tags: c#

I can not find the right way to transfer data to UI from children class as in title. What is the best way if I'd like to transfer data from children class or double children class ?

for example:

Form class:

```
private async void Bt_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 DataGridDataSource dataGridDataSource = new DataGridDataSource(_progressBar);
            dataSource = dataGridDataSource.GetDataSource();
}
```

DataGridDataSource class:

```
public DataTable GetDataSource()
{
  DataTable gardensTable = loader.GetGardensDataTable();
}
```

Loader class:

```
[...]
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
 if (gardensDetails.ContainsKey(row[2].ToString()))
                {
                    _log.AddToLog($"Found production duplicate: + {row[2].ToString()}", Color.Red);
                    string result =  _log.GetLogAsRichText(true);

                    continue;
                }
}
[...]
```

How can I transfer this `string result` to Form class?

I was looking for some similar topic but could not find solution.

Comment: If this functionality is being invoked by the UI layer, wouldn't you just return the result from the method?  It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.

Comment: @David I updated Loader class. I would like to update RichTextBox in UI layer foreach found element in this loop.

Comment: To visualize for you. In UI layer I have form with command prompt. I would like to add a message  for each found result. My question is how can I update command prompt from UI during loop or how can I transfer data from children class to parent class

Comment: @GuineaPigTaco: I'm afraid your question is very unclear.  Perhaps you could provide a [mcve] which demonstrates what you're trying to do and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: You want to return the DataTable and a string? Options are a class with a DataTable and a string parameter, Tuples, out Parameter and presumably some more. Where does _log come from? Is its something the Form has also access to?

Comment: So you chose to write a GUI-Application (which is fine) that has an integrated "Command prompt" (which I take for a CLI-Window or the like) - which still _can_ make sense for some use cases - and you allow the user to initiate UI updates from this CLI, of which you want each result line be printed on that CLI as well as be reflected in the GUI ?? Did I get that right?